# Objective-C – NSString copy property memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, nsstring, copy

I have an `NSString` declared as `@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *text` in a class. When I want to get this data from the text variable I call from my other class `NSString *text = self.objectInstance.text`. After doing an analyze Xcode says on the line that I'm declaring the text variable

> **1**. Property returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count

And then after that line

> **2**. Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

What I don't understand is that I neither write alloc, new, or copy thus I shouldn't need to release this object?

Comment: That's a bit strange in fact. Are you sure the you didn't rewrite by yourself one of the getter methods and this one returns a copied or retained version of the object?

Comment: 100% sure that I didn't rewrite the getter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong.

I used the property name `newFoo` which made the compiler think I returned a new object.

So note to self: understand cocoa naming conventions.